# NotImplementedError: 'pop' not supported on frozendict

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm adapting a module for Odoo v9 community

It uses frozendict, but everytime I try to use a feature, it throws:

```
NotImplementedError: 'pop' not supported on frozendict
```

The code is as follows:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type=False,
                    context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    journal_obj = self.pool.get('account.journal')
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    # remove the entry with key 'form_view_ref', otherwise fields_view_get
    # crashes
    #context=dict(context)
    context.pop('form_view_ref', None)
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).\
        fields_view_get(cr, uid,
                        view_id=view_id,
                        view_type=view_type,
                        context=context,
                        toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    type = context.get('type', 'out_invoice')
    company_id = user_obj.browse(
        cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id.id
    journal_type = (type == 'out_invoice') and 'sale_refund' or \
                   (type == 'out_refund') and 'sale' or \
                   (type == 'in_invoice') and 'purchase_refund' or \
                   (type == 'in_refund') and 'purchase'
    for field in res['fields']:
        if field == 'journal_id':
            journal_select = journal_obj._name_search(cr, uid, '',
                                                      [('type', '=',
                                                        journal_type),
                                                       ('company_id',
                                                           'child_of',
                                                           [company_id])],
                                                      context=context)
            res['fields'][field]['selection'] = journal_select
    return res
```

Following [this](http://poncesoft.blogspot.com/2015/03/solucion-error-notimplementederror.html) I've added this code to the line:

```
if context is None:
    context = {}
    journal_obj = self.pool.get('account.journal')
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    context=dict(context)
    context.pop('form_view_ref', None)
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).\
```

Instead of:

```
if context is None:
    context = {}
    journal_obj = self.pool.get('account.journal')
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    context.pop('form_view_ref', None)
    res = super(AccountInvoiceRefund, self).\
```

As You can see I've added `context=dict(context)`, but still get the same error.

Any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `frozendict` is, um, frozen.  You can't `pop()` it.

Comment: lol, but what function should be proportional in this case? copy() instead of pop()?

Comment: `pop()` removes the key/value pair (and returns the value it removed).  You can't do that with a frozendict.  `copy()` does something completely different.

Comment: I've changed that line to get(), but get same error, still references pop(), no idea why, gotta keep trying, and see if also I get some other comment tho, Thank You very much!

Comment: get() partially solved it, lol, Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contexts are [frozendict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict) objects that you cannot directly modify. This has been implemented on version 9 from what I am aware,

If you want to modify the context in your code you have to use methods provided by Odoo's API, take a look at the definition of the method named `with_context` on `openerp/models.py` around line 5460. It is sufficiently documented and you can find many examples on the source files as to how it is used.

Comment: I'll check it out, Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to get over this would be to copy the frozen dictionary to another dictionary and then pass that dictionary to the method either as an argument or if you are using the new api, use the 'with_context' method.

Here is an example:

```
ctx = dict(self._context)
self.with_context(ctx).write({'invoice_line': []})
```

As you can see in the above example the _context is copied to ctx and then with_context is used to pass the new modified context.